# How to get a JS script in php code after posting

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a html form that posts to a php page. 
On the php page I want to display a textarea with formatting options, which requires js scripts. When the form POSTs to the php page the scripts are not applied (I get a plain textarea) but if I go directly to the .php page the textarea is displayed with the formatting options (script ran successfully).
Let me put my code so its easier to understand

html form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);          </script>           
</head>
<body>
<form id="formOne" action="submitForm.php" method="post">
Enter your text below:</p>
<textarea name="userText" cols="70" rows="25"></textarea><br>
<p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</div>

</form>
</body>
```

php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php   
$file="testing.html";
//$current = $_POST['userText'];
$current = file_get_contents($file);
echo "<textarea name=userText2 cols=70 rows=25>".$current."</textarea>";    

?>
```

As you can see I included the scripts in the php in the head tag.
Now, if I click submit on the html page I am directed to the php page BUT the textarea doesn't display with the formatting.
However if I go directly to the php page the textarea has the formatting options.

So it seems to me when I POST to the php page the scripts are not detected/read?

I tried different things such as

```
echo '<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>';
```

as well as

```
<?php
$current = file_get_contents($file);
?>
 <script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
<?php
  --rest of php code here--
?>
```

to see if the script would run. But no success.

Is there something with the way that POST works that wouldn't allow it to read/run js scripts?

Answer (score 0):

POST wouldn't impact the js scripts in the way you mention. Try changing:

```
echo "<textarea name=userText2 cols=70 rows=25>".$current."</textarea>";
```

to

```
?><textarea name="userText2" cols="70" rows="25"><?php echo $current; ?></textarea><?php
```

It's possible the lack of quotes on the textarea name property was causing issues.

Comment: I just used your code and while the value I submitted in the form wasn't used for anything, the contents of testing.html did in fact show up inside a text area with the WYSIWYG editing toolbar.

Comment: For me, when I submit the form the contents of testing.html does not show up inside a text area with the WYSIWYG editing toolbar. Only if I refresh the page or go directly to the file. I dont think its a browser issue either....

Comment: Outside the textarea, if you output the data from testing.html is it there? file_get_contents() can also return false so you'll want to run a check like $content === FALSE to see if it was successful in reading the file.

Comment: yes. there are no problems with reading the data from the file

Comment: Do you have this running on a server somewhere so I can see what the output on the submtiForm.php page is when the script is run?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37202/discussion-between-chris-rasco-and-user2615490)

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the example on my server and it works perfectly. No idea what gets in the way on your server. Just for comparison here is my code:

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method=post action=frm.php> 
<textarea rows=8 cols=60 name=userText>This is some simple <b>markup</b> text.</textarea>
<input type=submit name=ok value=ok>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(nicEditors.allTextAreas);</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php   
$current = $_POST['userText'];
echo "<textarea name=userText2 cols=70 rows=25>$current</textarea>";    
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hm. Maybe I'm having a server issue rather than with the code. Although the issue only persists when you hit submit. If I refresh the php page or go to it directly it works fine